# Keyboard shortcuts don't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 15.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 and ALL my Keyboard shortcuts are broken.

I mean shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+any arrows.

I checked keyboard settings and all is turned on.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Am using notebook y50-70.

Comment: Do they start if you run `gnome-settings-daemon` command ?

Comment: Hell yeach.  Its working :D But only if this command is running :P

Comment: Good ! Add this command to Startup Applications or create a .desktop file for this job in /home/yourusername/.config/autostart.  If adding to Startup Applications doesn't do it sometimes , go with second option - that always works.  For more info just look up how to create .desktop file. I'm kinda in a rush but I will come back and post this as an answer later

Comment: Thats work ! THX so much :P

Comment: No problem buddy , I'll post an answer later,  so accep and upvote. That's the best way to thank people on this site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `gnome-settings-daemon` isn't starting on boot, for some reason. The workaround to that is to add `gnome-settings-daemon` to Startup Applications or add it as a `.desktop` entry, into `/home/yourusername/.config/autostart/` directory. The `.desktop` entry could be named `gnome-settings-daemon.desktop` and look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-settings-daemon
Hidden=false
Name=gnome-setting-daemon
```

This is my guess on why that daemon isn't starting: Ubuntu 15.04 , from what I've heard, has switched for different system for starting processes at boot - there used to be `upstart` and 14.04 (which is what I use) has that. Meanwhile 15.04 uses `systemd` . My guess is that this transition has broke some things, but hopefully by the time we get to next LTS release, everything will be fixed

Comment: Sadly this doesn't appear to work in 16.04. Installing and attempting to run gnome-settings-daemon in 16.04 results in the error `** (gnome-settings-daemon:4159): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down`

Comment: What is the command for Fedora 26?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this via terminal, is a bug.

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-qt5
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove appmenu-qt5
```

then log out and probe... this works for latex

Answer (score 0):

In my case the gnome-settings-daemon process was hang:

```
0 D alex   3798  3587  0  80   0 - 472136 rpc_wa Apr18 tty2    00:00:17 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
```

I just killed it and it reloads automatically. After that everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a clean install to Lubuntu 18.04 I found myself with the same issue, hotkeys were not working.
After reading openbox-lxde help web pages I noticed that the required software packages were missing.
When installing the OS I recalled having selected a minimal install; I thought that would account for the missing packages.
The working solution I applied was to issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt install openbox-lxde-session
sudo openbox-lxde --reconfigure
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to your home directory.

```
$cd ~
$ls -a
```

You can see `.gconf` directory.
If you remove this directory you will come back to your default desktop settings.

```
rm -rf .gconf/
```

`Restart`

It is an easier way of resetting back to your default desktop configuration.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: That will delete a lot of other settings and is a way to agressive solution. Don't do it!

Comment: GConf doesn't delete any important configuration, it only changes the desktop environment configuration.
As per the definition, GConf is a system for storing application preferences. It is intended for user preferences; not configuration of something like Apache, or arbitrary data storage.
Yes, it is an aggressive step if you have done a lot of desktop configuration changes but you might not know which thing you have messed up, so becomes very difficult to recover.
It is an easier way of resetting back to your default desktop configuration.