# Can't restore default text size

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I have never asked a question in an online forum before, but a few years of reading them have **emboldened** me, so here goes.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. While in the Unity "Keyboard" app, "Shortcuts" tab, "Universal Access" group, I changed "Increase text size" from "Disabled" to "Shift+Ctrl+>" and "Decrease text size" to "Shift+Ctrl+<". I tried the ">" shortcut and the text size *did* increase. However, I later decided to revert back to the smaller text, and could not. Neither shortcut worked anymore.

I searched online and found several possible solutions, neither of which has worked:

1. As per one suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616537/keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work), I tried **`~$ rm -rf .gconf/`** followed by a reboot. Alas, when it failed I noticed the negative score on the suggestion. Doh! Newbie error. Other than failing, no obvious ill effects. (A new .gconf directory has been created, and it no longer has a desktop subdirectory, which is where my changes to the default would have gone, I believe, so I think this is all as would be expected?)
2. As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration), I installed and ran **`~$ unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`**. This ran successfully (only when I switched to Python 3 BTW), but did not restore the text size.

I understand from elsewhere that there is a history to how configurations are handled in Unity, along the lines of gconf vs dconf etc. While my immediate concern is an answer to the above problem, I will appreciate any feedback, links etc. of a more general educational nature, on this or virtually any topic related to open sourcing.

Comment: If you still have _unity-tweak-tool_ installed open its UI from dash and go to Fonts section, there you can adjust font size and scaling. Hope it helps.