# Combination key like ctrl or alt or shift doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, android-studio

I have problem using combination keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>. For example when I want to copy selected text I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>,but it isn't working. Or when I want to select all text, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but this also doesn't work. In android studio all combination keys, doesn't work. When I open settings> keyboard> shortcuts , I can't edit shortcuts , because when I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for shortcut to copy, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> never gets entered , just <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616537/keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work) post recommends running gnome-settings-daemon. Hope this helps.<br>
Andrew.

Comment: How I can open .desktop entry ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks dear, but its not working. In my Ubuntu I can't use every combination keys in all OS, not just in Android Studio. For example I want to undo my changes, but doesn't work Ctrl + z like all  shortcuts inside Android studio.

Comment: Today I founded my problem.I use external keyboard for typing with laptop, because my laptop keyboard isn't working fine .Now when use laptop everything is working.But when use External keyboard, combination key isn't working.I know should be change layout keyboard.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those keys are not global. Gnome Terminal for instance uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for cut and paste. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste.

Comment: Thanks dear, this is work. But in Android studio, I can't use shortcuts like ctrl + alt or ctrl + alt + l for reformating code ant etc